# Apache Reverse proxy SSL issues

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, proxy, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have on my hostaname `https://servername/phpmyadmin/` installed `phpmyadmin`. 
I wanted to change the url and "adopt" the certificate of domain and use it on `db.domain.tld`, but I can't get it working.

Here is configuration of my ProxyPass in `ISPConfig` hostname where `11.22.33.44` is placeholder for server IP.

```
ProxyRequests off
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /phpmyadmin/ /
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 11.22.33.44 db.domain.tld

ProxyPass "/" https://11.22.33.44/phpmyadmin/ connectiontimeout=10000 timeout=10000
ProxyPassReverse "/" https://11.22.33.44/phpmyadmin/
```

Here is errors what I get in error log

```
[Tue Feb 18 09:18:57.640945 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 7804:tid 139734462269184] [client IPv6-placeholder:44762] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[Tue Feb 18 09:18:57.640950 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 7804:tid 139734462269184] [client IPv6-placeholder:44762] AH01097: pass request body failed to 11.22.33.44:443 (11.22.33.44)
```

Response in my browser is

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

Comment: Are you using a wildcard SSL certificate?

Comment: @Panki it is multi domain certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget to add solution. Here it is after time.

```
TimeOut 10000

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=On [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /phpmyadmin/ /
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain servername.host.tld db.domain.tld

ProxyPass "/" https://servername.host.tld/phpmyadmin/ connectiontimeout=10000 timeout=10000
ProxyPassReverse "/" https://servername.host.tld/phpmyadmin/
```